# How to get Name instead of ID in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, oracle11g

i have created a table

```
create table suppliers1(
sup_id NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
sup_name VARCHAR2(40),
sup_address varchar2(50),
sup_phone NUMBER(15));
```

insert data on the table

> ```
> INSERT  INTO suppliers1 (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE)
> VALUES (100,'PPS','Bds',99545414);
> INSERT  INTO suppliers1 (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE)
> VALUES (200,'Abcd','Dhaka',0295469);
> INSERT  INTO suppliers1 (SUP_ID,SUP_NAME,SUP_ADDRESS,SUP_PHONE)
> VALUES (300,'Xyz','Ctg',0896547556);
> ```

and another table  is
`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Product  (
> item_id   NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
> item_name VARCHAR2(50) not null,
> sup_id NUMBER(20),
> unit_id  NUMBER(10) ,
> CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (sup_id) REFERENCES
> suppliers1(sup_id)
> );
> ```
>
> and insert data product table
>
> ```
> INSERT  INTO Product(item_id,item_name,sup_id) values(03,'Product1',100);
> INSERT  INTO Product(item_id,item_name,sup_id) values(02,'Product2',200);
> INSERT  INTO Product(item_id,item_name,sup_id) values(01,'Product3',100);
> ```
>
> and finally  i have load product table  in datagrid using the command
>
> ```
> OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  product", con);
>             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
> ```
>
> and show data  in GridView
>
> ```
> ITEM_ID   ITEM_NAME   SUP_ID
> 1     Product1        100
> 2     Product2        200
> 3     Product3        100
> ```
>
> **it's work well but  i  need show  SUP_NAME instead  of SUP_ID**
>   such as

```
>     ITEM_ID   ITEM_NAME   SUP_NAME
>     1     Product1        PPS
>     2     Product2        Abcd
>     3     Product3        PPS
```

[please see the pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx9I8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sup_ID is in your product table, and Sup_Name is in your suppliers1 table.

But in your code you only select from the product table.
So you need to do a join between the two tables in the sql in your code.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Data\\SODB.db;Version=3;");
dbConnection.Open();

dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
SQLiteDataAdapter adp = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT item_id, item_name, sup_name FROM  product, suppliers1 where product.sup_id = suppliers1.sup_id", dbConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
adp.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

dbConnection.Close();
```

This will generate a result which looks like this;

[image: Form Picture]

Comment: That's not what you asked in your question.  Please clarify the question and tell us exactly what you want.  And show the code how you generate this programmatically today

Comment: thanks,  i have insert data to product table using some text field using c#   and need show data SUP_NAME instead of SUP_ID on  data grid,

Comment: sup_name dose not exsist  on product table  product table contain sup_id

Comment: Yes, That's why you do a join to supplier1 where is does exist.  Did you try it?

Comment: i have edit the post and attached screen  caption  now i think i have clarify you

Comment: Sorry man, but the solution works.  I have now created a test program with SQlite and put all the code above and a screenshot of the result.